# Compartilhar Sessão usando Redis

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

Eu tenho o seguinte setup na AWS:

1. Aplicação com php5.6
2. Aplicação com Laravel 6
3. LoadBalancer
4. ElasticCache Redis

O LoadBalancer separa determinada rota pra aplicação com PHP e outras rotas para o Laravel
Instalei no PHP a extensão php5-redis e funcionou perfeito a conexão
Instalei no Laravel o pacote predis e fiz a configuração também

As sessões estão salvando assim no PHP:

```
"PHPREDIS_SESSION:3mm1j1s38io0qqsjo9h1i5k0e7" "1440" "id_log_acesso|s:8:\"22684247\";last_session|s:26:\"3mm1j1s38io0qqsjo9h1i5k0e7\";"
```

E no Laravel salva assim:

```
_sessao_aplicacao_cache:8IITIOGBIDNWfuF3FpY47c03FSJx2yGzyQzsh3ny" "7200" "s:223:\"a:3:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"StJV71z6IVC7W1Zme2m0GcI4wuNRhEtnWfwkGT7s\";s:9:\"_previous\";a:1:{s:3:\"url\";s:65:\"http://172.31.23.41/check-status-6d1127a34c48cd9722d16b7e20aaee70\";}s:6:\"_flash\";a:2:{s:3:\"old\";a:0:{}s:3:\"new\";a:0:{}}}\";"
```

As 2 instancias compartilham o mesmo domínio, quem gerencia tudo é o LoadBalancer

Minha dúvida é: Como eu compartilho a mesma sessão para as 2 aplicações?

Grato!

Comment: Quando há a intensão de compartilhar sessões entre aplicações 
 deve-se redefinir em ambas aplicações as funções de armazenamento de sessão com [session_set_save_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-set-save-handler.php) de forma que operem sobre os mesmos recursos.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo. A pergunta é boa e a situação existente no mercado de trabalho.

Comment: Não chegou nenhum negativo pra mim aqui, mas vou dar uma olhada no session_set_save_handler()

Tentar equiparar ele com o do Laravel..

Grato pela dica @AugustoVasques

Comment: Chegou um negativo sim, pois eu havia dado um positivo na pergunta.

Comment: Ah pena :/ Não contabilizou pra mim aqui, podia ter pelo menos justificado o negativo

Comment: @AugustoVasques tu tem algum exemplo pratico disso? 
Procurei mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse :(

Comment: Se eu achar algo deixo o link mais tarde.